# No token inside auth header when using @auth0/angular-jwt for Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm really confused. I've implemented `@auth0/angular-jwt` to secure my requests to my NodeJS backend. I've did this globally inside my `app.modules.ts` file:

```
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

imports     : [
  HttpClientModule,
  JwtModule.forRoot({
    config: {
      tokenGetter,
      whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:3000']
    }
  })
]
```

When I now sent an email for example inside my email service, I'm not getting any token in the header on my NodeJS server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  sendEmail(receiver: string, subject: string, content: string, args: object) {
    const uri      = 'http://localhost:3000/api/sendmail';
    const emailObj = {
      receiver,
      subject,
      content,
      args
    };

    return this.http.post(uri, emailObj, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
}
```

This is my header from the request on my NodeJS server:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '410',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) ' +
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 ' +
    'Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/contact',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here? When I manually call `localStorage.getItem('access_token')` in the console, I'm getting an empty result. Did I missed something?

**Update**

When I return a hard coded token this way, it's still not visible in the headers:

```
export function tokenGetter() {
  return 'kYO}b!^°YfdZq;9IcQi387./&V*k?mamw+X&[1uU°!x~69hqn~t4/No*m_[BMa}s';
}
```

Comment: You need to save the token in localStorage first... show the code that does that

Comment: Are you sure that your node.js server sends the token via header and not as a response in the buddy? You might check the body of you http request

Comment: @David There is no code for saving the token. I thought this is done somehow by the lib? There is nothing in the documentation about that. What is your idea for saving the token? Can I replace the getting from the local storage with a token I want?

Comment: Jwt are returned by a server Api once you logged in, so no you cannot replace it with what you want

Comment: @David There is no login available. I just want to secure my email sending to my backend.

Comment: @David So would you say it makes more sense to just encrypt a token, sent it with the request to the NodeJS server, decrypt it, validate and and continue with the task or return error if the token is wrong? Because there is no login or something like this.

Comment: Technically, there is no point encrypting anything in the front end, since anybody can access the code. Normal flow is that user user logs in and gets a JWT token ,which is then included in all API requests and checked server side to make sure the user is authotised to use the API